# Meteor Как достать из Jquery переменную и как запустить сами кости

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, meteor

Помогите достать из Jquery переменную . У меня есть кости. Они выдают число и это число мне нужно записать в базу . Как это сделать

Вот кубики(контроллер):

```
import { Controller } from 'angular-ecmascript/module-helpers';
import { Gamesdb,Dice } from '/lib/collection';

export default class GamesCtrl extends Controller {
  constructor() {
    super(...arguments);





 this.helpers({
      data() {
        return Gamesdb.find();
      }
    });
  }

  play($event) {
  //работает добавление класса , а дальше идти не хочет
    $(event.target).addClass('activated');
    if($(this).hasClass('activated')){
  $('#platform').removeClass('stop').addClass('playing');
  $('#dice')
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#platform').removeClass('playing').addClass('stop');
    var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    var x = 0, y = 20, z = -20;
    switch(number){
        case 1:
          x = 0; y = 20; z = -20;
          break;
        case 2:
          x = -100; y = -150; z = 10;
          break;
        case 3:
          x = 0; y = -100; z = -10;
          break;
        case 4:
          x = 0; y = 100; z = -10;
          break;
        case 5:
          x = 80; y = 120; z = -10;
          break;
        case 6:
          x = 0; y = 200; x = 10;
          break;
    }

    $('#dice').css({
      'transform': 'rotateX(' + x + 'deg) rotateY(' + y + 'deg) rotateZ(' + z + 'deg)'
    });

    $('#platform').css({
      'transform': 'translate3d(0,0, 0px)'
    });

    $('#point').html(number);

  }, 3000);
};
}
}

GamesCtrl.$name = 'GamesCtrl';
```

Вот сам html :

```
      <div id="background"></div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <p id="point">0</p>
<button id="play" ng-click="games.play($event)">Play</button>

  <div id="platform">
    <div id="dice">
      <div class="side front">
        <div class="dot center"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="side front inner"></div>
      <div class="side top">
        <div class="dot dtop dleft"></div>
        <div class="dot dbottom dright"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="side top inner"></div>
      <div class="side right">
        <div class="dot dtop dleft"></div>
        <div class="dot center"></div>
        <div class="dot dbottom dright"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="side right inner"></div>
      <div class="side left">
        <div class="dot dtop dleft"></div>
        <div class="dot dtop dright"></div>
        <div class="dot dbottom dleft"></div>
        <div class="dot dbottom dright"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="side left inner"></div>
      <div class="side bottom">
        <div class="dot center"></div>
        <div class="dot dtop dleft"></div>
        <div class="dot dtop dright"></div>
        <div class="dot dbottom dleft"></div>
        <div class="dot dbottom dright"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="side bottom inner"></div>
      <div class="side back">
        <div class="dot dtop dleft"></div>
        <div class="dot dtop dright"></div>
        <div class="dot dbottom dleft"></div>
        <div class="dot dbottom dright"></div>
        <div class="dot center dleft"></div>
        <div class="dot center dright"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="side back inner"></div>
      <div class="side cover x"></div>
      <div class="side cover y"></div>
      <div class="side cover z"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Опишите подробней проблему и вопрос. Что именно не получается и что уже пробовали сделать?

Comment: Нужна сделать рабочей логику кубика , не получалось не как. Не лезет ничего . Выводило иногда ошибку `$ is not defined` что-то типо  такого

Answer (score 1, accepted):

например можно так

```
play(e,t) {
   t.$('#platform').removeClass('stop').addClass('playing');
}
```

Установите пакет [jquery](https://docs.meteor.com/packages/jquery.html) с [атмосферы](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/jquery) командой

```
meteor add jquery
```